Snakemake: using workflow.source_path with apptainer containers
If I need resources to be located via workflow.source_path(), then it cannot be used in the case where my rule runs in a container since the workflow path is not passed. The --apptainer-args can be used to mount directories, but the user doesn't typically know the workflow path, which ends up in a cache directory. Is there any way to configure the apptainer bind paths from the Snakefile itself?
As an aside, it feels like this directory should be mounted by default by snakemake.
